# Adverbial complements for [I listened to ...] vs [I worked as ...]

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, grammatical-roles

(1) I listened to the lecture at school. --> The lecture was listened to by me at school.
(2) I worked as a secretary at the company. --> A secretary was worked as by me at the company.
Both listen and work are intransitive verbs.

The second passivization seems unusual to me.
In (1) "to the lecture" is an adverbial complement.

My question is about 2) "as a secretary" - is it an adverbial complement?

[Is this Adverbial a complement or an adjunct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/180520/is-this-adverbial-a-complement-or-an-adjunct) gives a test for being a complement or adjunct. Does this test work for sentence (2)?

Comment: "A secretary was worked by me" means you took sexual advantage of her.

Comment: *I listened* and *I worked* are both grammatical sentences, so by your linked definition, their would-be prepositional phrases are adjuncts.

Comment: The passive version of the second sentence would require rephrasing: ***The position of*** *secretary was worked **at** by me at the company.* But I'm not sure if your question is asking how to form a grammatical passive version at all, or if it's asking specifically about if it can be done with the same basic wording as in the active version.

Comment: @JasonBassford Thanks, I'm more interested in whether "as a secretary" is an adverbial complement or adjunct. The two sentences I gave seem structurally the same, but can't be passivized in the same way, so maybe the prepositional phrases "as a secretary" and "to the lecture" have different semantics. I'm not sure.

Comment: @ParsonsDaniel Well, how about this: *My work **as a secretary** was (done / worked at) by me at the company.*

Comment: @JasonBassford, interesting. Thank you. You've changed work to a noun, but "as a secretary" still has scope over the word "work" like it does in "I worked as a secretary".

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/601225/2085).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*As a secretary* is a predicative adjunct in this case:

> As a secretary, I worked at the company.
>
> I, as a secretary, worked at the company.
>
> I worked at the company as a secretary.

The preposition *as* is not specially picked by the verb; we may do a variety of things *as a secretary*.

> She had many responsibilities *as a secretary*.
>
> *As a secretary*, she interacted with a good deal of the company's clients.

Also, the postition of the adjunct is quite free in the clause, as compared to that of a complement:

> He hired her as a secretary.
>
> As a secretary, He hired her.
>
> He, as a secretary, hired her.

The latter two would have a different interpretation than the first. Here, *hired* takes an object and a prepositional phrase complement headed by *as*, but if we move the prepositional phrase out of its basic position, it is instead interpreted as a predicative adjunct with the subject of the sentence *he* as predicand.

Predicative adjuncts cannot be passivised since they are not complement to the verb.

> She was hired as secretary.
>
> *Secretary was worked as by her.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that predicative adjuncts can't be passivized. In your examples "He hired her as a secretary" and "He, as a secretary, hired her", the scope of "as a secretary" changes. "He" is the secretary in the second, and "hired" seems to go with "as a secretary". Does that mean the scope of the prepositional phrase affects whether it is a complement or an adjunct?

Comment: Hi. Not sure why the answer is downvoted, but it has helped me better understand my problem. I'm too new to upvote. Any comments on what might be wrong could be helpful.

Comment: Glad it helped.