# What is a verb called that requires an adverbial complement?

Tags: grammar, argument-structure

A transitive verb is one that has (requires?) an object. What is a verb called if it requires an adverbial complement? For example:

*We are staying in a hotel.* [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_complement)

Here, *in a hotel* is non-optional. It is an adverbial complement of the verb *stay*. Is there a name for such verbs which require adverbial complements?

Comment: It's not a complement. The preposition phrase "in a hotel" is functioning as an adjunct (your adverbial). It cannot be a complement since it is not licensed by the head "staying". Note that when we talk of a complement completing the construction of another element, the syntactic concept construction is preferable to the semantic concept meaning.

Comment: Compare with this question and answer (https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/180520/is-this-adverbial-a-complement-or-an-adjunct), which also explores the adverbial complement but gives no specific term in the lengthy answer for a *verb that requires an adverbial complement*. I expect there isn't one, since I'm unaware of a guide that tries to strictly delineate those verbs from other verbs.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin The simple fact is that there is no such thing as an 'adverbial complement'. 'Adverbial' and 'complement' are distinctive functions, and a phrase cannot function as both at the same time. Note that complements must be licensed by the head.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin The crucial feature of  complements is that their admissibility depends on the presence of an appropriate head (this is called 'licensing'). By contrast, the occurrence of adjuncts (adverbials) is not restricted this way. They are optional modifiers, quite distinct from complements. The two functions cannot combine to form an "adverbial complement". Note that the term 'adverbial' is misleading, but that's another story.

Comment: @BillJ Let's agree to disagree, since disagreeing about the existence of an occasionally-used term is beside the point of the question. (That's also why I deleted my previous comment.)

Comment: @BillJ What would you call it then? Another example "Please keep still"

Comment: I don't agree that "stay" requires anything. "Are you going or staying?" "We are staying."
"What do you want me to do?" "I want you to stay!" "If you stay, I leave."

Comment: @user8356 That's when there's an implied *here*. You can't walk up to an old friend and say "Yesterday I stayed", unless they already know where you are talking about. It doesn't make sense. However, "Yesterday, I stayed at a hotel" does. This meaning of _stay_ is anyhow not the same as the one meaning "remain here"!

Answer (score 1):

There is no term for a verb that requires an adverbial specifically. However, if one defines "valency" to indicate the number of a verb's arguments and defines its required dependents (such as the prepositional phrase in your example) to be arguments, then the verb could be considered "divalent". The first argument would be the subject ("we") and the second would be the prepositional phrase ("in a hotel"). The verb "put" is often considered "trivalent" for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the previous answer:

> The area of grammar that explores the nature of predicates, their
> arguments, and adjuncts is called valency theory. Predicates have a
> valence; they determine the number and type of arguments that can or
> must appear in their environment.
>
> Most theories of syntax and semantics acknowledge arguments and
> adjuncts, and the distinction is generally believed to exist in all
> languages. However, the terminology varies.
>
> *Arguments* must be distinguished from *adjuncts*. While a predicate **needs** its arguments to complete its meaning, the adjuncts that appear with a predicate are optional; they are not necessary to
> complete the meaning of the predicate.
>
> Arguments and adjuncts The basic analysis of the syntax and semantics
> of clauses relies heavily on the distinction between arguments and
> adjuncts. The clause predicate, which is often a content verb, demands
> certain arguments. That is, the arguments are necessary in order to
> complete the meaning of the verb. The adjuncts that appear, in
> contrast, are not necessary in this sense. The subject phrase and
> object phrase are the two most frequently occurring arguments of
> verbal predicates.[3] For instance:
>
> - ***Jill** likes **Jack***.
> - ***Sam** fried **the meat***.
> - ***The old man** helped **the young man***.
>
> Each of these sentences contains two arguments (in bold), the first
> noun (phrase) being the subject argument, and the second the object
> argument. *Jill*, for example, is the subject argument of the
> predicate *likes*, and *Jack* is its object argument. Verbal
> predicates that demand just a subject argument (eg *sleep, work,
> relax*) are intransitive; verbal predicates that demand an object
> argument as well (eg *like, fry, help*) are transitive, and verbal
> predicates that demand two object arguments are ditransitive (eg
> *give, lend*).
>
> When additional information is added to our three example sentences,
> one is dealing with adjuncts, eg
>
> - *Jill **really** likes Jack.*
> - *Jill likes Jack **most of the time***.
> - *Jill likes Jack **when the sun shines***.
> - *Jill likes Jack **because he's friendly***.
>
> The added phrases (in bold) are adjuncts; they provide additional information that is not
> necessary to complete the meaning of the predicate *likes*. One key
> difference between arguments and adjuncts is that the appearance of a
> given argument is often obligatory, whereas adjuncts appear
> optionally. While typical verb arguments are subject or object nouns
> or noun phrases as in the examples above, they can also be
> prepositional phrases (PPs) (or even other categories). The PPs in
> bold in the following sentences are arguments:
>
> - *Sam put the pen **on the chair***.
> - *Larry does not put up **with that***.
> - *Bill is getting **on my case***.
>
> We know that these PPs are (or contain) arguments because when we
> attempt to omit them, the result is unacceptable:
>
> - **Sam put the pen*.
> - **Larry does not put up*.
> - **Bill is getting*.
>
> Subject and object arguments are known as core arguments; core
> arguments can be suppressed, added, or exchanged in different ways,
> using voice operations like passivization, antipassivization,
> applicativization, incorporation .... **Prepositional arguments**,
> which are also called **oblique arguments**, however, do not tend to
> undergo the same processes.

[[Wikipedia; adjusted)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(linguistics))]

So, with the terminology used here, the PP 'on the chair' (etc) in the final set of acceptable examples is a *prepositional argument* or an *oblique argument*. It is a locative, of course. [To be fair, the article contains 'A further division blurs the line between arguments and adjuncts' / 'Obligatory vs optional arguments.' There is no consensual view for this subject.]

> *The verb 'put' requires three arguments (ie, it is trivalent).* [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_role#:%7E:text=For%20example%2C%20the%20verb%20put,lexical%20entry%20for%20the%20verb.)]

Answer (score -1):

BillJ commented:

> It's not a complement. The preposition phrase "in a hotel" is functioning as an adjunct (your adverbial). It cannot be a complement since it is not licensed by the head "staying". Note that when we talk of a complement completing the construction of another element, the syntactic concept construction is preferable to the semantic concept meaning.

Comment: Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148694/discussion-on-answer-by-alphabet-what-is-a-verb-called-that-requires-an-adverbia); please do not continue the discussion here.